google sheets app script generate 4 random number generation
I have the following code, which is used to generate random numbers at range(1,1). I use triggers to generate it at intervals.
function triggerAutoRefresh() {  
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('random').getRange(1, 1).setValue(getRandomInt(1, 200));
}
// Basic Math.random() function
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

I now have an idea:

After range(1,1) generates a random number, copy this number to range(1,2) after 1 minute;
After range(1,1) generates a random number, copy this number to range(1,3) after 2 minutes;
After range(1,1) generates a random number, copy this number to range(1,4) after 3 minutes.
In this way, I can get random numbers of different time series in 4 cells. How can I modify the code to complete this function?

Currently, I can only generate a random number at intervals. So I copied the code four times and used four triggers to roughly implement my idea. But I will receive a warning: Exception: Too many simultaneous invocations. So I want to use one code and one trigger to complete it, but I have no idea now.
----Additional explanation----
As shown in the figure, the four random numbers are currently independent of each other, and are generated by 4 triggers, each triggered once every 5 minutes.

My idea is to improve it and complete it with only one trigger every 5 minutes. But I can't let this random number change at the same time.
As shown in the figure, suppose range(1,1) generates a random number 105 at 0:00; then at 0:01, copy 105 to range(1,2); at 0:02, copy 105 to range(1,3); and at 0:03, copy 105 to range(1,4).

Can you post a sample input/output data? Also, can you confirm that this script should only be run once and then generated the said outputs one at a time per minute up to 3 minutes? Your description is somewhat confusing, kindly explain further for clarity.

I can get random numbers of different time series in 4 cells. Do you just need 4 random numbers or does it have to be at different times ?

What I need is 4 random integers, but these 4 random numbers cannot change at the same time.

Generate 4 Random Numbers on Code Run
Just add a for loop in your Script and use Utilities.sleep() to have a time interval.
This is based on:

I now have an idea:

After range(1,1) generates a random number, copy this number to range(1,2) after 1 minute;
After range(1,1) generates a random number, copy this number to range(1,3) after 2 minutes;
After rang(1,1) generates a random number, copy this number to range(1,4) after 3 minutes. In this way, I can get random numbers of different time series in 4 cells. How can I modify the code to complete this function?


Sample Output:

Added Script:
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    ss.getRange(1,i).setValue(ss.getRange(1, 1).getValue());
    ss.getRange(1, 1).setValue(getRandomInt(1, 200))
    Utilities.sleep(60000);
  }
ss.getRange(1, 1).setValue(getRandomInt(1, 200));

As you can see for a loop less than equal 4 and for each iteration it generates a random number on the start and move the generated number after  in every minute.
Whole Script:
function triggerAutoRefresh() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('random');
  for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    ss.getRange(1, i).setValue(ss.getRange(1, 1).getValue());
    ss.getRange(1, 1).setValue(getRandomInt(1, 200))
    Utilities.sleep(60000);
  }
  ss.getRange(1, 1).setValue(getRandomInt(1, 200))
}

// Basic Math.random() function
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}


References:

Utilities.sleep()



Thanks. I ran it, range(1,1) always changed every minute. What I wanted was that range(1,1) only changed once each time it was triggered. Inspired by yours, I modified:
function triggerAutoRefresh() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('random');
ss.getRange(1, 1).setValue(getRandomInt(1, 200))
Utilities.sleep(60000);
ss.getRange(1,2).setValue(ss.getRange(1, 1).getValue());
Utilities.sleep(60000);
ss.getRange(1,3).setValue(ss.getRange(1, 1).getValue());
Utilities.sleep(60000);
ss.getRange(1,4).setValue(ss.getRange(1, 1).getValue());
}
